# Прокрутка на элемент

Tags: jquery

Только начал изучать jquery  и понадобилось сделать прокрутку через ссылку на блок rsform (class). Очень долго гуглил, но не нашел подходящих уроков на эту тему. Можете кинуть примерный код?

Comment: Если обясните более понятным языком, то попробуем направить в нужную сторону.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужны якоря.Якоря можна реализовать либо только средствами Html,либо js.

[Якоря](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya)

[Изменение прокрутки: scrollTo, scrollBy, scrollIntoView](http://learn.javascript.ru/metrics-window#%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-scrollto-scrollby-scrollintoview)